# Importing dependency works in one file, but not the other

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I am starting adventure with Vuex, and making some auth module. Found some examples that I am trying to follow, but got stuck trying to use axios in store. My store has separated index, actions, getters etc. files.

Action `login` works when it's in actions in `store/index.js`, but when I put it in the `store/actions.js` file, it says `axios` is undefined.

**store/index.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'
// import example from './module-example'

Vue.use(Vuex)

/*
 * If not building with SSR mode, you can
 * directly export the Store instantiation
 */
import state from './state'
import getters from './getters'
import mutations from './mutations'
import actions from './actions'


export default function(/* { ssrContext } */) {
  const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      // example
    },
    namespaced: false,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions,
    state,
    // enable strict mode (adds overhead!)
    // for dev mode only
    strict: process.env.DEV,
  })

  return Store
}
```

**store/actions.js**

```js
export default {
  login({ commit }, user){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      commit('auth_request')
      axios({ url: 'http://localhost:3000/login', data: user, method: 'POST' })
        .then(resp => {
          const token = resp.data.token
          const user = resp.data.user
          localStorage.setItem('token', token)
          axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
          commit('auth_success', token, user)
          resolve(resp)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          commit('auth_error')
          localStorage.removeItem('token')
          reject(err)
        })
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

That should be only in actions.js file, because that's where you use it. And yes, you need to import it in every file separately or use globals.

Answer (score 0):

define axios globaly in app entry point(app.js or smth like that):

```
global.axios = require('axios')
```

Comment: that worked, however it doesn't seem right. now in my app entry I have

`import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
global.axios = require('axios')`

Why it works in index.js but not in actions.js ?